# CiviMail Change the Track Opens Tracking URL to a pretty URL

Tags: civimail

I'm using the Track Opens option in CiviMail.

In CiviCRM for Wordpress the regular mail tracking url looks something like this: https://mywebsite.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=123&qid=1234

It is fine for a lot of recipients and tracking works perfectly.

However I have had reports that because the url links to a file within the Wordpress plugins directory, some systems suspect the links to be malware or spyware so the Urls are removed from the email.

Without hacking any civi files, is it possible to change the Url to something pretty like: https://mywebsite.co.uk/civimail/?u=123&qid=1234

I'm thinking it would involve the htaccess file?

Thanks

Comment: You might get more views posting on stackoverflow, since it's more of a web server config question than civicrm.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out and my solution is as follows:

1. Change the CiviCRM Resource URL to something of your choice e.g. https://mywebsite.co.uk/mycrm
2. Add a mod_rewrite rule to your htaccess file (above the Wordpress rules):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^mycrm(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps someone.